# What is the difference between $("*", $("#container1")) and $("#container2").find("*")?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between `$("*", $("#container1"))` and `$("#container2").find("*")`?. 
I usually use AA, but not well in that case can be more ultil the odd.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function(){

    var endTime = 0, iniTime = 0, counter = 0;

    iniTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $("*", $("#container1")).each(function()
    {
        counter++;
    });
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    $("#result").append("<div>Container enviroment -> "+counter+" "+(endTime-iniTime)+"</div>");

    endTime = 0; iniTime = 0; counter = 0;
    iniTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $("#container2").find("*").each(function()
    {
        counter++;
    });
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    $("#result").append("<div>Find method -> "+counter+" "+(endTime-iniTime)+"</div>");

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="container1"> 
        <span></span>...
        </div>
    <div id="container2"> 
        <span></span>...
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Result:

IE8
Container enviroment -> 9752 282
Find method -> 9752 296

Chrome 4.0
Container enviroment -> 9752 65
Find method -> 9752 66

Firefox
Container enviroment -> 9752 135
Find method -> 9752 125

Safari
Container enviroment -> 9752 46
Find method -> 9752 51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used properly, the context selector is no different from find. Resig has stated that he dislikes the context selector and would prefer people use .find(), since it makes more sense semantically.

There's a lot of ways to screw up context; for example, passing a string does not work and causes the selector to default to parsing the entire document. I'm fairly sure your example is using the context correctly (no time to test), but again, using .find() beats this uncertainty.

Comment: But don't you think giving it a starting context would prevent it from having to scan the whole DOM, thus making the selector perform better?  Depending on the page, this could have a significant performance impact.

Comment: I did notice his tests, but I am not sure if they are relevant due to the impractical markup structure.

Comment: +1 totally agree. If it helps the OP, there's a nice blog post on the context here: http://beardscratchers.com/journal/jquery-its-all-about-context

Comment: @Josh Stodola - The initial selector from which find is called can be thought of as the starting context - I think it would still be the same thing. If I say `$('div.blah').find('.foo')` that's not going to scan the whole DOM for `.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the context selector must implicitly call **find()** itself.

Best to just use **find()** for simplicity.

**EDIT:  source code from 1.3.2:**

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, [context])
// (which is just equivalent to: $(content).find(expr)
```