# What is the difference between....?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between $(“*”, $(“#container1”)) and $(“#container2”).find(“*”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626010/what-is-the-difference-between-container1-and-container2-fin)

What is the difference between

`jQuery('.classname', this.frame)` and `this.frame.find('.classname')` ?

Thanks!

Comment: ... It depends if `this.frame` is a jQuery object not.

Comment: [Reading the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) helps too: *"Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`."*

Answer (score 4):

Nothing, if you look at jQuery's source code, `jQuery('.classname', this.frame)` just calls `jQuery(this.frame).find('.classname')`

[See line 192](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

For that matter, you can just read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) which as Felix King pointed out states:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Answer (score 1):

the second example will blow up because `this.frame` is not a jquery object. other than that, they are equivalent.

you may have meant `$(this.frame).find('.classname')`

Comment: There is nothing to say that it's not a jQuery object.

Comment: @JamesAllardice There is nothing to say that it is a jQuery object. ;P